# Running Java Jar via Jenkins

Tags: java, jar, jenkins

I have a Java jar file which takes two csv files as an input. I tried to run this jar via Linux command line and it works fine.

Here is what i tried on Linux command line:

```
java -jar /home/test/Download.jar
```

I am trying to do the same via Jenkins in Execute shell but I am getting error:

```
Couldn't load file: test1.csv
Couldn't load file: test2.csv
information possible empty
```

These are the csv files that Jar takes as input.

I have given chmod 777 permission to all files.

Comment: do you get a stacktrace? that seems like a quite limited error message, doubt that's all the jvm gives as result

Comment: How do you load the files?Are thay part of your jar?

Comment: yes they are part of it. Jar needs to read data from these two external csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that's because of the location of the `test[12].csv` files. Try printing out the `getAbsolutePath()` for those `File` entries that you want to load: I'm sure they will point to a non-existing location.

I suppose those files are *"next to"* your `Download.jar` file. Now when you're executing a Jenkins job, the actual working directory is the workspace of the job (check the console log of the job on the web interface for the details). Either copy the files there or use absolute references.